# How do I display inputted digits from the Twilio Gather method?

Tags: ruby, twilio

I'm new to Twilio and coding in general, and I'm having trouble accessing params from the Gather method. I'm using Sinatra to code this app. Basically, my app is trying to do the following:

1. User inputs their number and a delay to a form.
2. My twilio number will call that number after the specified delay.
3. A voice will ask the user to input a number using the Gather method.
4. Call will be redirected to a new url where the voice will count from 1 up to the number inputted.

I want a history log displayed below where it shows the phone number and delay from the form, and the number param gathered during the call. I can see the digits inputed in the Twilio log but don't know how to access it. What's the best way to go about displaying this info in my index.erb file?

```
  <% unless @calls.nil? %>
      <% @calls[1..10].each do |call| %>
      <tr>
          <td><%= call.start_time %> </td>
          <td><%= call.to_formatted %> </td>
          <td><%= delay input %></td>
          <td><%= number inputted %></td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can only access the input digits from [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) within the call, so if you want to read this out later you will need to save the value in your own database and reconcile the data yourself.

Your app would then look a bit like this:

The action that `<Gather>`s the digits:

```
post "/calls" do
  twiml = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    r.Gather action: "/process_gather" do |g|
      g.Say "Please enter a digit and I will count up to it."
    end
  end
  twiml.to_xml
end
```

Then you can receive the `Digits`, save them alongside the Call SID, and read out the numbers. (I'm imagining a `CallRecord` model that acts like ActiveRecord here.)

```
post "/process_gather" do
  number = params["Digits"].to_i
  call_record = CallRecord.new(call_sid: params["CallSid"], number: number)
  call_record.save!
  twiml = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    twiml.Say "Here are your numbers."
    twiml.Say (1..number).to_a.join(', ')
  end
  twiml.to_xml
end
```

Then, for your log page, you can retrieve the calls from the API, as I assume you're doing. You'd then want to return the `CallRecord`s from the database using the `CallSid`s from the API and you can zip the two records together and read out the results into your view.

Does that help at all?

Comment: Yes, that helps a lot, thanks so much! I knew storing it in a database was the probable way to go, but wanted to make sure whether I could just grab the info directly from Twilio's logs.